# Integrate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$ in parallelepiped

Tags: integration, proof-verification

The question is how to find this integral:

$$\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}dx\int\limits_{y_1}^{y_2}dy\int\limits_{z_1}^{z_2}dz\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$

where $$x_i,y_i,z_i \in \mathbb{R}$$

I think that idea to solve it in spherical coordinates is bad due to non reduceable inequalities, so I try to find it in Cartesian coordinates. So, here is some additional formulas:

$$\begin{align}
\textbf{I}_1 &=  \int\limits_a^b dx \ln \left| \alpha+\sqrt{\beta^2+x^2} \right|  \\
&= x \ln\left| \alpha+\sqrt{\beta^2+x^2} \right| \Bigg|_{x=a}^b - 
\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_a^b \frac{d(\beta^2+x^2)}{\sqrt{\beta^2+x^2}(\alpha+\sqrt{\beta^2+x^2})}
\\&= \Big[ \beta^2+x^2=\xi^2 \Big] \\&= x\ln\left| \alpha+\sqrt{\beta^2+x^2} \right| \Bigg|_{x=a}^b - 
\int\limits_{\sqrt{\beta^2+a^2}}^{\sqrt{\beta^2+b^2}} \frac{d \xi}{\alpha + \xi}
 \\ &=b \ln\left| \alpha+\sqrt{\beta^2+b^2} \right| - a \ln\left| \alpha+\sqrt{\beta^2+a^2} \right| -
\ln\left| \frac{\alpha+\sqrt{\beta^2+a^2}}{\alpha+\sqrt{\beta^2+b^2}} \right|
\end{align}$$
So, using $\textbf{I}_1$ we can calculate this:
$$\begin{align}
\textbf{I}_2&=\int\limits_a^b dx \ln \left| \frac{\alpha_1+\sqrt{\beta_1^2+x^2}}{\alpha_2+\sqrt{\beta_2^2+x^2}} \right|  \\
&= b \ln \left| \frac{\alpha_1+\sqrt{\beta_1^2+b^2}}{\alpha_2+\sqrt{\beta_2^2+b^2}} \right| - 
a \ln \left| \frac{\alpha_1+\sqrt{\beta_1^2+a^2}}{\alpha_2+\sqrt{\beta_2^2+a^2}} \right| \\&- 
\ln \left| \frac{\alpha_1+\sqrt{\beta_1^2+a^2}}{\alpha_1+\sqrt{\beta_1^2+b^2}} \right| +  
\ln \left| \frac{\alpha_2+\sqrt{\beta_2^2+a^2}}{\alpha_2+\sqrt{\beta_2^2+b^2}} \right|\end{align}
$$
Now, we are able to calculate the main integral:
$$\begin{align}
\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}dx\int\limits_{y_1}^{y_2}dy\int\limits_{z_1}^{z_2}dz\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} 
&= \int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}dx\int\limits_{y_1}^{y_2}dy \ln \left| z + \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \right| \Bigg|_{z=z_1}^{z_2} \\
&= \int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}dx\int\limits_{y_1}^{y_2}dy \ln \left| \frac{z_2+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z_2^2}}{z_1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z_1^2}} \right|  \\&=
\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}dx \Bigg[ y_2 \ln \left| \frac{z_2+\sqrt{x^2+z_2^2+y_2^2}}{z_1+\sqrt{x^2+z_1^2+y_2^2}} \right| - 
y_1 \ln \left| \frac{z_2+\sqrt{x^2+z_2^2+y_1^2}}{z_1+\sqrt{x^2+z_1^2+y_1^2}} \right| \\&-
\ln \left| \frac{z_2+\sqrt{x^2+z_2^2+y_1^2}}{z_2+\sqrt{x^2+z_2^2+y_2^2}} \right| + 
\ln \left| \frac{z_1+\sqrt{x^2+z_1^2+y_1^2}}{z_1+\sqrt{x^2+z_1^2+y_2^2}} \right| \Bigg]\\
&= \ldots\end{align}
$$
And each integral here calculate with expression for $\textbf{I}_2$. But it looks very crazy, am I on the right way?

UPD: Here is the answer. Could someone approve it?
$$\begin{align}
\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}dx\int\limits_{y_1}^{y_2}dy\int\limits_{z_1}^{z_2}dz\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}  &=
-(y_1+1) \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}+z_1}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}+z_1}\right|\\&+
y_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}+z_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}+z_2}\right| \\&+
\ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}+z_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}+z_2}\right|+
y_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}+z_1}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}+z_1}\right|+
\ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}+z_1}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}+z_1}\right|\\&-
y_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}+z_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}+z_2}\right|-
\ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}+z_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}+z_2}\right|
-x_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}+z_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}+z_1}\right|\\&+
x_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}+z_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}+z_2}\right|+
x_1 y_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}+z_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}+z_1}\right|\\&-
x_1 y_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}+z_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}+z_1}\right|\\
&+x_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}+z_1}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}+z_1}\right|
-x_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}+z_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}+z_2}\right|\\
&-x_2 y_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}+z_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}+z_1}\right|
+x_2 y_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}+z_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}+z_1}\right|\end{align}$$

Comment: Couldn't you use new lines? [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx30y.png) is how your equations render on my screen.

Comment: It should become correct after few seconds after page is loaded. If not, let me know, please, I will fix

Comment: I suggest you to use `\begin{align} ... \end{align}` next time.

Comment: @danielleontiev it won't render correctly no matter how many seconds one wait. The layout depends on the rendering mode. For the browser I use, out of the 5 rendering modes, only the HTML-CSS mode knows how to wrap the very long lines in this question.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, I'll try to wrap it with align environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thr help of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160756/53743) post, I've got the answer:

\begin{multline*}
\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}\int\limits_{y_1}^{y_2}\int\limits_{z_1}^{z_2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} dx dy dz = \\
= \frac{1}{2}\Bigg[z_1^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_1 y_1}{z_1 \sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}}\right)+y_1^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_1 z_1}{y_1 \sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}}\right)+x_1^2 \arctan\left(\frac{y_1 z_1}{x_1 \sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}}\right)- \\
-z_1^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_2 y_1}{z_1 \sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}}\right)-y_1^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_2 z_1}{y_1 \sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}}\right)-x_2^2 \arctan\left(\frac{y_1 z_1}{x_2 \sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}}\right)-z_1^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_1 y_2}{z_1 \sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}}\right)-\\
-y_2^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_1 z_1}{y_2 \sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}}\right)-x_1^2 \arctan\left(\frac{y_2 z_1}{x_1 \sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}}\right)+z_1^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_2 y_2}{z_1 \sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}}\right)+y_2^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_2 z_1}{y_2 \sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}}\right)+\\
+x_2^2 \arctan\left(\frac{y_2 z_1}{x_2 \sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}}\right)-z_2^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_1 y_1}{z_2 \sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}}\right)-y_1^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_1 z_2}{y_1 \sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}}\right)-x_1^2 \arctan\left(\frac{y_1 z_2}{x_1 \sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}}\right)+\\
+z_2^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_2 y_1}{z_2 \sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}}\right)+y_1^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_2 z_2}{y_1 \sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}}\right)+x_2^2 \arctan\left(\frac{y_1 z_2}{x_2 \sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}}\right)+z_2^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_1 y_2}{z_2 \sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}}\right)+\\
+y_2^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_1 z_2}{y_2 \sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}}\right)+x_1^2 \arctan\left(\frac{y_2 z_2}{x_1 \sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}}\right)-z_2^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_2 y_2}{z_2 \sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}}\right)-y_2^2 \arctan\left(\frac{x_2 z_2}{y_2 \sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}}\right)-\\
-x_2^2 \arctan\left(\frac{y_2 z_2}{x_2 \sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}}\right)-y_1 z_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}+x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}-x_1}\right|-x_1 z_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}+y_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}-y_1}\right|-x_1 y_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}+z_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}-z_1}\right|+\\
+y_1 z_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}+x_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}-x_2}\right|+x_2 z_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}+y_1}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}-y_1}\right|+x_2 y_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}+z_1}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}-z_1}\right|+y_2 z_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}+x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}-x_1}\right|+\\
+x_1 z_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}+y_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}-y_2}\right|+x_1 y_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}+z_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}-z_1}\right|-y_2 z_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}+x_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}-x_2}\right|-x_2 z_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}+y_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}-y_2}\right|-\\
-y_1 z_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}+x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}-x_1}\right|+x_1 z_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}+y_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}-y_1}\right|+x_1 y_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}+z_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}-z_2}\right|-y_2 z_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}+x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}-x_1}\right|-\\
-x_1 z_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}+y_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}-y_2}\right|-x_1 y_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}+z_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}-z_2}\right|-y_1 z_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}+x_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}-x_2}\right|-x_2 z_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}+y_1}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}-y_1}\right|-\\
-x_2 y_1 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}+z_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_1^2+z_2^2}-z_2}\right|+x_2 y_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}+z_1}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_1^2}-z_1}\right|+y_2 z_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}+x_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}-x_2}\right|+x_2 z_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}+y_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}-y_2}\right|+\\
+x_2 y_2 \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}+z_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2}-z_2}\right|\Bigg]
\end{multline*}